# Discrete math statement $\rightarrow$ plain English. $\left(Longer\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found this one more challenging, I think the length of it confused me the most.

Given Statement:
$\forall x \in \Bbb N \left[\left(\exists y \in \Bbb N \left(2 \le y \land y \lt x \land y \mid x \right)\right) \to \left(\exists z \in \Bbb N \left(2 \le z \land z \le \sqrt x \land z \mid x\right)\right)\right]$

So far I have written it as:
For all $x$ in the natural numbers and there exists $y$ for all natural numbers where $z$ is smaller or equal to $y$ if and only if $y$ is smaller than $x$ if and only if $y$ is a divisible of $x$ then, $\cdot \cdot \cdot$

I only wrote it up to the $\rightarrow$, but not sure if it makes sense and furthermore if it's correct. Thus, can I continue like this for the next part.

Any edits of my existing statement and any help in converting to plain English is welcomed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you want $z\leq z$ or should it be $2\leq z$?

Comment: Going the other way around: how would you quantify the statement "*any positive integer $x$ which is not a prime has a proper divisor $z$ no larger than $\sqrt{x}\,$*".

Comment: @martin.koeberl it was supposed to be $2 \le z$, edited the question.

Comment: We have it already : [forall-x-in-mathbbn-exists-y-in-mathbbn2-leq-y-land-yx-land-y-x](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2219022/forall-x-in-mathbbn-exists-y-in-mathbbn2-leq-y-land-yx-land-y-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any natural number $x$. If we can find a natural number $y$ between 2 and $x-1$ (inclusive) such that $y$ divides $x$, then there exists another natural number $z$ between 2 and $\sqrt(x)$ (inclusive) that divides $x$ as well.